# Where do I find the allowed maximum number of symlink dereferences?

Tags: symlink

In the book *The Linux Programming Interface*, it says

> The kernel imposes limits on the number of dereferences to
>   handle the possibility of circular chains of symbolic links.

Where can I find this limit?

Comment: I can think of 2 very different ways to answer this question... either with the API to find the limit within a program, or with a pointer to the kernel code that enforces the limit.

Comment: @WumpusQ.Wumbley Really? I was hoping for a particular file in procfs.

Comment: I went looking for the API, I believe I found it (`SYMLOOP_MAX` defined in POSIX [`<limits.h>`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604499/basedefs/limits.h.html) and more dynamically, [`sysconf(_SC_SYMLOOP_MAX)`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604499/functions/sysconf.html)) but it seems to be unimplemented in Linux.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looking at the 4.18 kernel sources, I see a constant named `MAXSYMLINKS` in `include/linux/namei.h` whose value is `40`.

Reference: https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/include/linux/namei.h#L12

```c
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/path.h>
#include <linux/fcntl.h>
#include <linux/errno.h>
    
enum { MAX_NESTED_LINKS = 8 };
    
#define MAXSYMLINKS 40
```